# Why my tableView did not display anything

Tags: objective-c, uitableview

i want select over 50 in the first section,and others in the second section ,but there is no value display in tableView ,and when i use NSlog("%@",self.over50) ,there is no reaction

```
-(UITableViewCell*)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"UITableViewCell" ];
    NSArray* items = [[BNRItemStore shareStore] allItems];


    self.itemsUnder50 = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    self.itemsOver50 = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];


    for (BNRItem *item in items) {
        if (indexPath.section ==0) {
            [self.itemsOver50 addObject:item];
            cell.textLabel.text = [self.itemsOver50[indexPath.row] description];



            NSLog(@"%@",self.itemsUnder50);
        }

        else if(indexPath.section == 1){
            [self.itemsUnder50 addObject:item];
            cell.textLabel.text = [self.itemsUnder50[indexPath.row] description];
        }
    }

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: set break point this method and check one by one your method call and check items is null or not.

Comment: Have you return number of section 2 in delegate method? @N.nnd

Comment: i have,but there is no reaction

Answer (score 0):

connect the datasource and delegate of the tableview to the viewController